# Hash#slice like method that returns nil if given key are not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using `Hash#slice` method in my rails environment.

`slice` method works like this:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, d: 4 }.slice(:a, :c, :d)
=> {:a=>1, :d=>4}
```

But I want to return a `nil` if given key are not present, like this:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, d: 4 }.slice(:a, :c, :d)
=> {:a=>1, :c=>nil, :d=>4}
```

This is what I wrote for the function, is there better way to write this function?

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}
keys = [:a, :c, :d]
keys_not_present = keys.map { |key| key unless hash.has_key?(key) }.compact
keys_not_present = keys_not_present.zip([nil]*keys_not_present.size).to_h
hash.slice(*keys).merge(keys_not_present)
```

The order of the hash is not concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `reduce` of the terms you are interested in:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}
[:a, :c, :d].reduce({}) {|h, k| h[k] = hash[k]; h }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}
[:a, :c, :d].collect { |k| [k, hash[k]] }.to_h
 => {:a=>1, :c=>nil, :d=>4}
```

You can monkey patch `Hash` to add it as a method:

```
class Hash
  def my_slice(*keys)
    keys.collect { |k| [k, self[k]] }.to_h
  end
end

 {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}.my_slice(:a, :c, :d)
 => {:a=>1, :c=>nil, :d=>4}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution; it creates a new Hash from the `keys` array with `nil` values, and merges that with the results of the slice:

```
> Hash[keys.zip].merge(hash.slice(*keys))
 => {:a=>1, :c=>nil, :d=>4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you're not fond of using reduce (though I am) is to map the keys to an array of tuples and then call to_h. Like so:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}
[:a, :c, :d].map{|k| [k, hash[k]]}.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to monkey patch `slice` (if you're sure you always want it to behave this way). You can find the source for Hash#slice [here](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice).

Original Slice

```
class Hash
  def slice(*keys)
    keys.each_with_object(Hash.new) { |k, hash| hash[k] = self[k] if has_key?(k) }
  end
end
```

All we need to do is remove the `if has_key?(k)` and now we have the "new" slice method,

```
class Hash
  def slice(*keys)
    keys.each_with_object(Hash.new) { |k, hash| hash[k] = self[k] }
  end
end
```